# Biblical Hebrew Textbooks Written in Voweled Hebrew

Tags: hebrew

The title may be a bit confusing; what I'm looking for is a Hebrew Grammar textbook (preferably biblical Hebrew, but modern is fine too) that is completelly written in Hebrew but its ment for non-hebrew natives. With that, I'm looking for a text that is voweled for learning the vocabulary as you go while learning the grammar.

I used a bit of the book Hebrew from scratch (יברית מן ההתחלה) but its for modern hebrew.

Anyone know something similar to that.

Comment: Nop, will try ty

Comment: I have a book on my shelf I picked up long ago. It's written in Hebrew as Khumash Latalmid and in English as 'the Student Bible'. It's got all the Masoretic points and the texts are biblical (it starts with Breshit, naturally). It seems to be a cram book for Bar/Bat Mitsve. Not a lot of grammar, actually; just what comes up naturally in memorizing the Torah. Copyright 1950, Hebrew Publishing Co, New York. Editor Mordecai H. Lewittes.

Comment: @dan04 Or [languagelearning.se]?

Comment: You mean all the text of the book, the grammatical descriptions and word definitions are themselves in Biblical Hebrew? That's not going to exist, there just isn't enough modern vocab to do that. And who would the audience be?